# Issue Creating a Joint Channel in AWS Managed Blockchain - getting failed to create deliver client error

Tags: amazon-web-services, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, aws-cli

I'm using the [AWS Managed Blockchain Getting Started Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/managed-blockchain/latest/managementguide/get-started-joint-channel.html) and I have ran into an issue with Step 8.7.

I am getting the following error message:

> Receiving an Error: failed to create deliver client: failed to load config for OrdererClient: unable to load orderer.tls.rootcert.file: open : no such file or directory

We're running on an AWS Linux EC2. What is causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure you are using the right TLS cert path in the command. Please note that AWS documentation suggests to use `--cafile /opt/home/managedblockchain-tls-chain.pem --tls`. Passing this parameter in your command should help you get rid of the above error.